# VBA .range method for copy/paste resulting in #N/A

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste, named-ranges

Currently I have a macro which, using a control file, cycles through a list of external files performing the following processes:

- opens file
- inserts two variables from the control file
- allows the external, newly opened file to calculate based on the inserted variables
- extracts several ranges of data from the opened files, bringing them back to specified ranges in the control file

Due to the number of files being opened (30), and the somewhat large nature of said files (on average 15k KB), I have been attempting to optimize the script.

Currently, I am replacing all use of the clipboard (copy/paste) with the .range method, wherein a source range is equated to a destination range. This is working on several of the items, but I am running into an issue on a particular range that needs to be moved to the control file.

The range moves correctly from source to destination, but the fourth column of data in the range that is moving results in #N/A once arrived at the destination. The source data is all formula driven (vs hard coded data), so it seems odd that only the 4th column is experiencing the issue. The only thing that is different about this 4th column is that it is non-contiguous with the first three columns, but is the 4th column of the named range.

This is the particular piece of code that is resulting the #N/A:

```
**Workbooks(Control_File).Sheets(Project).Range(ProjRange).Value = 
Workbooks(Open_ES).Sheets("Sale Refi Dist. Template").Range(Project & 
"_Tranche_1").Value**
```

Below is the full script:

```
Sub NAV_Waterfalls()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

As_Of_Date = Range("As_Of_Date")
Control_File = Range("Control_File_Name")


Set Project_Rng = Range("Project_Range")
Dim cell As Range
Dim FPath As String


Z = Range("Project_Range").Rows.Count

For Each cell In Project_Rng

Workbooks(Control_File).Sheets("Asset Control - NAV").Activate
Project = cell

FPath = Range(Project & "_FilePath")
Open_ES = Project & " - Equity"
NAV = Range(Project & "_NAV")

Dim book As Workbook
Set book = Workbooks.Open(FPath, 2, ReadOnly:=True)


'Delete last run data
Workbooks(Control_File).Sheets(Project).Activate
Rows("7:500").Select
Selection.ClearContents

'Insert Date
Workbooks(Control_File).Activate
Workbooks(Control_File).Sheets("Asset Control - 
NAV").Range("As_of_Date").Copy Workbooks(Open_ES).Sheets("Sale Refi Dist. 
Template").Range(Project & "_Date_Input")


'Insert Project NAV
Workbooks(Control_File).Activate
Workbooks(Control_File).Sheets("Asset Control - NAV").Range(Project & 
"_NAV").Copy Workbooks(Open_ES).Sheets("Sale Refi Dist. 
Template").Range(Project & "_NAV_Input")



'Tranche 1
On Error Resume Next

With Workbooks(Open_ES).Sheets("Sale Refi Dist. Template").Range(Project & 
"_Tranche_1")
Tranche_Rows = .Rows.Count
Tranche_Cols = 4
End With

Workbooks(Control_File).Sheets(Project).Activate
Range("A" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select.Activate

StartRow = ActiveCell.Row
Lastrow = Tranche_Rows
Let ProjRange = "A" & StartRow & ":" & "D" & StartRow + Lastrow - 1



**Workbooks(Control_File).Sheets(Project).Range(ProjRange).Value = 
Workbooks(Open_ES).Sheets("Sale Refi Dist. Template").Range(Project & 
"_Tranche_1").Value**

Application.CutCopyMode = False

Workbooks(Open_ES).Close SaveChanges:=False
Workbooks(Control_File).Save

Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

The actual script has portions that repeat the section labelled "Tranche 1" for additional tranches, but will likely be re-wrote into a loop for all tranches, so I have excluded this piece.

Comment: UPDATE: In one of the files from which the source data is being taken from, I created a range that is linked to the data that I was originally extracting, but the linked test range was made to be contiguous regarding the four columns. After redefining the named range to reference the test range, the function worked correctly. Still hoping for a solution aside from creating custom, contiguous ranges in each of the 30 reference files.

Comment: You can't perform a direct assignment of values using ranges which aren't contiguous.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tim, I have stepped through the code and have observed that the newly opened workbook source ranges are intact and not experiencing any issues.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, any idea as to why the copy paste function can operate on non contiguous ranges?

Comment: It's a different operation, and has different rules.